# Filter rows with duplicates or triplicates++ by matching key and screening columns

Tags: awk, filter, duplicates, screen

I'm getting stuck with duplicate / triplicate filtering complexity. Solution preferably awk, but could also be sort -u or unique etc.

I want to filter rows with either unique or exact duplicate/triplicate etc. values in the first three columns. The whole line including the fourth column which shouldn't match anything should be printed. Consider this tab-separated table:

Edit: $2 and $3 values don't have to be compared within one row. As recommended, I changed $3 values to 2xx.

```
name value1 value2 anyval
a 1 21 first
b 2 22 second
b 2 22 third
c 3 23 fourth
c 3 28 fifth
d 4 24 sixth
d 4 24 seventh
e 4 25 eighth
e 4 25 ninth
f 7 27 tenth
f 7 27 eleventh
f 7 27 twelveth
f 7 27 thirteenth
g 11 210 fourteenth
g 10 210 fifteenth
```

Line 1 is unique and should be printed.
Lines 2 + 3 contain exact duplicate values, one of them should be printed.
Lines 4 + 5 contain different value in col 3 and should be kicked out.
Lines 6 + 7 are duplicates, but they should be kicked out because lines 8 + 9 contain the same value in in col 2.
Same for lines 8 + 9.
One of the lines 10 to 13 should be printed.

Desired output:

```
a 1 21 first
b 2 22 second
f 7 27 tenth
```

... or any other of b and f.

---

What I've got so far but failed:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++ && !seen[$2]'
```

prints all duplicate lines based on col 1

```
a   1   21  first
b   2   22  second
c   3   23  fourth
d   4   24  sixth
e   4   25  eighth
f   7   27  tenth
```

---

```
awk '!seen[$1]++ && !seen[$2]++'
```

prints

```
a   1   21  first
b   2   22  second
c   3   23  fourth
d   4   24  sixth
f   7   27  tenth
```

---

Consequently, awk should print the desired result if:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++ && !seen[$2]++ && !seen[$3]++'
```

But the output is empty.

---

A different try: print dups in col 1, then again same procedure for col 2 and col 3 - doesn't work because there are dulicates in col 2

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $1}' file.txt |sort|uniq -d|grep -F -f - file.txt
```

prints first the duplicates in col 1 without "a", which I could cat later on

```
b   2   22  second
b   2   22  third
c   3   23  fourth
c   3   22  fifth
d   4   24  sixth
d   4   24  seventh
e   4   25  eighth
e   4   25  nineth
f   7   27  tenth
f   7   27  eleventh
f   7   27  twelveth
f   7   27  thirteenth
```

But again, I'm getting stuck with repetitive values (e.g. 4) spanning multiple columns.

---

I think the solution could be to define col1 singlets and multiplets and screen for repetitive values in all other columns, but that's causing massive stack overflow in my brain.

Comment: since you discard lines 6, 7 when reading lines 8, 9 I suspect you'll have to store the data in an array and print all its elements after looping through the whole file.

Comment: What is the point in keeping `b 2 2 second` but loosing `c 3 3 fourth`
because in `c 3 2 fifth` 3!=2?

Comment: I wasn't precise enough: Only the first three columns should be analyzed, the fourth column should not be considered and contains any value that will be printed.

Comment: @James Brown: Logical failure, corrected c 3 2 to c 3 8.

Comment: Are $2 and $3 values compared against each other?  If not perhaps change $3 values to be different than $2 values for the sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear of the requirements, but you can filter the records in stages...

```
$ awk '!a[$1,$2,$3]++{print $0,$2}' file | 
  uniq -uf4 | 
  cut -d' ' -f1-4

a 1 1 first
b 2 2 second
f 7 7 tenth
```

first `awk` filters all the duplicate entries based on first three fields and prints the second field to be used by the next process, unique filters only based on second field (now in forth position) and removes all copies of duplicates, cut gets rid of the extra key field.

**UPDATE**

For filtering both unique $2 and $3 fields, we have to revert back to `awk`

```
$ awk '!a[$1,$2,$3]++ {f2[$2]++; f3[$3]++; line[$2,$3]=$0} 
       END            {for(i in f2) 
                         for(j in f3) 
                           if((i,j) in line && f2[i]*f3[j]==1) print line[i,j]}' file | 
  sort

a 1 1 first
b 2 2 second
f 7 7 tenth
```

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't take into account the third column. I added two more lines to the table to show what I mean.